# Verifying MongoID in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, validation, fatal-error

I'm trying to check if strings are a valid MongoId via the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mongoid.isvalid.php

```
use MongoId;

if( !MongoId::isValid("id_string") )
{
    return false;
}
```

However doing this I end up with:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoId::isValid()

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this error myself too... Seems like this is the legacy mongo extension which allowed use of the `isValid()` method. The *new* mongoDB extension doesn't have an equivalent method.

Under the new mongoDB extension, if you try to construct a MongoId which isn't valid it will throw an `InvalidArgumentException`. Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-exception-invalidargumentexception.php

I've created a very basic function to do some level of checking that the id is as close as possible to the correct format of a MongoId:

```
function isValidMongoId($id) {

    return is_string($id) && strlen($id) == 24 && ctype_xdigit($id);

}
```